# Filling Hashmap without using put too much

Tags: java

For context: I need to fill a Hashmap with values corresponding to the input the user gives. 
1-20 in height and A to T in length. The user can specifiy these by input.

My question however is, how do I go around filling the Hashmap with values without repeating below 400 times?

```
hashmap.put(K key, V value)
```

the Hashmap itself looks like `HashMap<String, Square>` 
Square being a(empty for now) class.

Comment: Using a loop, maybe?

Comment: @JBNizet Nope. There's no way around it. He will have to copy and paste it 400 times.

Comment: Have a look at Java 8 Stream API.  For further help please provide incoming data.

Comment: Maybe use Java 8 `Collectors.toMap`? But this depends on the format of your input data. So, what exactly is the format like?

Comment: in Java 9 You have Map.of(...) method - http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V- or ofEntries in Your case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a loop e.g.

```
for(int i=1; i<=400; i++){
  //code to insert the key and value

  //insert to the hashmap
  hashmap.put(K key, V value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you have 400 elements then you are for sure using some kind of data structure(lists, arrays, whatever), now,  using java8 you can stream those, and collect it into a map...

```
List<Integer> myListOfKeys = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); //or your list with 400 keys
List<Long> myListOfValues = Arrays.asList(221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L);//same

Map<Integer, Long> myHashMap = IntStream.range(0, myListOfKeys.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> myListOfKeys.get(k), v -> myListOfValues.get(v)));

System.out.println(myHashMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your data in a format that has friendlier initialisation syntax, and convert it into a map in a loop.

For example:

```
Object[][] rows = new Object[][] { 
   { "A", 1, "red" }, 
   { "B", 5, "blue" },
   // ... etc. 
};

Map<String,Square> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Object[] row : rows) {
   map.put(
       (String) row[0], 
       new Square((Integer) row[1], (String) row[2])
   );
}
```

You can do the equivalent with streams too:

```
Map <String,Square> map = Arrays.stream(rows)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap( 
          row -> (String) row[0], 
          row -> new Square((Integer) row[1], (String) row[2])
     ));
```

( You specify a `HashMap` in the question. I don't know whether that's a slip of the tongue, or whether it's an important requirement to you. To guarantee a specific `Map` implementation use `Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapSupplier)` -- but you shouldn't often need this. As it happens the default does use a `HashMap`, but there's no guarantee it will stay that way).

---

As your code grows, you might choose to read data like this from a file.

---

Alternatively, just have 400 `map.put()` statements! You don't have to manually type each one. Use an editor that does regex search and replace (vi, Emacs, Atom, TextMate, most IDE editors). Start with a file like this:

```
a,1,red
b,5,blue
c,6,purple
... etc.
```

Regex search pattern:

```
([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

Replace with:

```
map.put("$1", new Square($2,"$3"));
```

(Details vary by editor)